# form_for with same attributes for different year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, form-for

trying to implement a form_for with different years having the same input.
I have two tables: Position (empty one) and PositionSteps (with year / company_name / position_title)

```
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :position_steps, dependent: :destroy
end

class PositionStep < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :position

  validates_uniqueness_of :year
end
```

For exemple, a person have to indicate the the position and the company he works for.
The first line is based on current information :

- 2020     Google    Sales (autocomplete with current info - that can be changed)
- 2021     Google    Head of sales
- 2022     Facebook  Head of marketing

  ```
      <%= form_for @score do |f| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.date_field :year, value: @default_year, class: "form-control" %>
         <%= f.text_field :company_name, value: @default_company_name, class: "form-control" %>
         <%= f.text_field :position_title, value: @default_position_title, class: "form-control" %>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.date_field :year, class: "form-control" %>
         <%= f.text_field :company_name, class: "form-control" %> 
         <%= f.text_field :position_title, class: "form-control" %>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.date_field :year, class: "form-control" %>
         <%= f.text_field :company_name, class: "form-control" %> 
         <%= f.text_field :position_title, class: "form-control" %> 
       </div>

       <%= f.submit "Validate", class: 'btn' %>
     <% end %>
  ```

Not really sure about the way to implement my form in my edit page and ta save the data the user will add in my new table

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use nested form for this purpose. The form could be for one position which can have multiple position steps or you can create a form for user which would have multiple positions and each position will have multiple position steps.

Comment: The Rails way to handle creating multiple resouces at once in a single syncronous form is by using [nested resources](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) together with [fields_for](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions-the-fields-for-helper). Creating/updating multiple resources from a single form without nesting is pretty complicated and you'll have to cobble it together yourself.

Comment: However you can also use AJAX to let the user remain on the same page while sending multiple separate POST requests to create each PositionStep as they fill out the form. From a UX perspective this is usually better then having a mega form that you have to fill out and only getting feedback after you have filled in a boatload of inputs.